# Datastage Column Mapping logic Based on column Value (Or any SQL function to do the same)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, datastage

I'm trying to find a solution in datastage (Or in SQL) - without having to use a bunch of if/else conditions -  where I can map value of one column based on value of another column.

Example -
Source File -

| ID | Header1 | Value1 | Header2 | Value2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Length | 10 | Height | 15 |
| 2 | Weight | 200 | Length | 20 |

Target Output -

| ID | Length | Height | Weight |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10 | 15 |  |
| 2 | 20 |  | 200 |

I can do this using Index/Match function of excel. Was wondering if datastage or Snowflake can look into all these fields similarly and automatically populate the value column to the corresponding header column!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think the best solution in DataStage would be a Pivot stage followed by a Transformer stage to strip out the hard-coded source column names.